# Does ActiveRecord cache table_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got an `ActiveRecord` class that needs to look at two different tables depending on a configuration switch, so I'm planning to do the following:

```
def table_name
  config_is_on? ? :table1 : :table2  
end
```

I'm wondering whether the `table_name` method is always called when queries are run against this model: the application is **not** going to be restarted when the configuration changes, so this value cannot be cached.

Does `ActiveRecord` always evaluate the `table_name` or just once during application startup / initialization? If it's cached how do I force it to evaluate `table_name` every time?

Comment: try `set_table_name` and check

Comment: Doing this on `development` will just give a false sense of security - the question is what happens on `production`

Comment: as per my knowledge it will work for production

Comment: @rewritten says if it's other than pg it will switch database i don't know about table will switch or not in apartment gem.i am using for my one of subdomain app with pg schema based

Comment: Just to clarify, I can't always call `set_table_name` when the configuration changes - I have no way of knowing when it does. It might be set directly into the DB outside of the app.

Comment: what is the point of this logic `config_is_on? ? :table1 : :table2`

Comment: You can add additional logic check if table exist then use this etc

Comment: It checks a configuration flag (fetched from the DB) to see which table to use. Both tables are identical in structure but have different data. The point is to be able to move the application to a different dataset in the future.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19143/discussion-between-amar-and-sudhir-jonathan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the table name, also the column definition. You'd better go with a schema setup like with the Apartment gem. Depending on some state of a request, the actual table search path in the database is set to something. So you can do two schemas, one with the first table, one with the second (the rest of tables may be on just one schema) and changing the search path you will get different data.